# Erro Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, microsoft-word

Estou desenvolvendo um código para converter um documento word em pdf. Quando executo a aplicação através do Visual Studio, a conversão é realizada e nenhum erro é apresentado. Quando executo a aplicação no servidor onde está instalado o IIS, o documento não é convertido e é retornado um erro.

Código:

```
            // Abrir Aplicacao Word
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            string WordFile = @"c:\Projetos\Conversoes\Word.docx";

            object filename = (object)WordFile;

            // Arquivo de Destino
            object newFileName = @"c:\Projetos\Conversoes\ArquivoConvertido.pdf";

            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            object onlyread = false;

            // Abrir documento
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, onlyread, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            // Formato para Salvar o Arquivo – Destino  – No caso, PDF
            object formatoArquivo = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

            // Salvar Arquivo
            doc.SaveAs(ref newFileName, ref formatoArquivo, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            // Não salvar alterações no arquivo original
            object salvarAlteracoesArqOriginal = false;
            wordApp.Quit(ref salvarAlteracoesArqOriginal, ref missing, ref missing);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordApp);
```

Erro:

Mensagem:

[1] Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

[2] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Evento:

[1] System.Web.HttpUnhandledException

[2] System.NullReferenceException

Local:

[1] Boolean HandleError(System.Exception)

[2] Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs)

Fonte:

[1] System.Web

[2] GestHos

Pilha:

[1] at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

[2] at GestHos.Documentos.Conversor.Converter.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Sim, já conferi isso.

Comment: Quando eu publiquei a aplicação já deveria ter ido, não? De toda forma, como posso conferir?

Comment: Sabe como posso conferir se ela foi publicada?

Comment: Bom.. na pasta bin do projeto realmente a DLL não se encontra. Porém, no servidor de desenvolvimento, onde está funcionando, também não se encontra.